# filtering the rows in R based on the values in columns

Tags: r, statistics, filtering, analysis

I have a .txt file in which there are 13 columns. the first one is Characters(names) and the next 12 are numbers. also there are 1000 rows. I want to filter out the rows in which even one column has the value less than 10. in other word I just need the rows with values equal or more than 10 in all columns. could you please let me know how I can do that in R?

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Looks like your first or early post. Providing sample input and sample output is the best way to get help. You can try something like this for example with a made up data frame: `df <- data.frame(x = 'a', y = sample(c(9, 10), 10, replace = TRUE), z = sample(c(9, 10), 10, replace = TRUE)); 
df[!rowSums(df[, -1] < 10), ]`

Comment: @Gopala: this is the results I got   "There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"

Comment: A commenter will only get a notification if you put an @ before their name, for example @Gopala. Regarding your question, you could use something like `apply(x>10,1,all)`, but this will also check your first column of characters

Comment: Similar to @Gopala solution, you can try `df[rowMeans(df[,-1] >= 10),]`, since any row with at least 1 value less than 10 will drop the mean below 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `which()` function in R to satisfy your condition. Create some test data:

`> test
          X1        X2        X3        X4
1   9.725585 10.067146  9.473320  9.959529
2  10.104124 11.278900  9.299356 10.317570
3   8.770733 11.092994  9.803285 12.078180
4  10.163150  9.233452  9.425293  9.968435
5   9.815270  9.932501  9.798252  9.194674
6  10.635158  9.175388 10.938356 10.611528
7  10.959444  7.766411  8.955005 10.712767
8   9.907442 10.123078  9.897276 10.467526
9   9.337628 10.811072 11.062031 10.426313
10 10.056789 11.029007 10.875958 11.160633`

using `which(test < 10, arr.ind = TRUE)` gives:

```
> head(which(test < 10, arr.ind = TRUE))
      row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   1
[3,]   5   1
[4,]   8   1
[5,]   9   1
[6,]   4   2
```

Then:

```
> sort(unique(which(test < 10, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```